# How to achieve pass-by-reference in recursive methods in Java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, pass-by-reference, inner-classes

What are the ways in which we can achieve/mock pass by reference in Java?
In order to check whether a linkedlist is a palindrome, i wrote the below code. It works/
But i would like to know if there are any other ways to achieve this without wring a wrapper class.

```
   class MyClass {
        ListNode mover = head;
        boolean b = true;
    }

public boolean checkPalindrome(){

        ListNode temp = head;

        int len = length()/2 + length()%2;

        MyClass myObj = new MyClass();

        int i =(len%2 == 1) ? len:len-1;

        while(i>1){
            myObj.mover = myObj.mover.next;
            i--;
        }
        boolean e = checkPalindrome(temp, myObj, len);
        return e;
    }

    public boolean checkPalindrome(ListNode head, MyClass ref, int len) {

        if(head == null || len == 0)
            return true;

        len = len-1;

        checkPalindrome(head.next,ref, len);
        ref.mover = ref.mover.next;
        ref.b = ref.b && (head.value==ref.mover.value);
        return ref.b;
    }
```

In order have the current location of "ref" object i wrote the MyClass wrapper. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: That doesn't look like it's going to be checking for a palindrome at all - it looks like it might be checking whether the first half of a list is equal to the second half of a list. However, it seems to me that you don't need your extra class at all - you just need to pass the `ListNode`, and use the return value of the recursive call (which you currently ignore). It doesn't help that the code you've provided wouldn't even compile - you're using a variable called `iterator` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I modified the iterator part.

Comment: Also it does check for the palindrome, that is the reason to use recursion, when recursion meets base case, the mover moves forward while heads rolls backwards and i compare both of them.

Comment: Also, if i change the return type, then i can no longer return the boolean right?

Comment: Where do you "roll backwards"? You're using `ref.mover.next` and `head.next`? Or is the point that you're moving the head iterator forward to the end in the recursive step, and only moving the `ref` one forward later? It's *very* confusing compared with starting off with one iterator at the start and one iterator at the end. I never suggested changing the return type - I suggested *using* the return value. However, now that I *think* I understand the convoluted way that you're effectively moving backwards, that might not help. Is this only a singly-linked list?

Comment: Yes, this is only singly-linked-list. I am moving the head iterator until half of the linked-list (look at no-arg checkPalindrome method). When it hits the base case (len = 0) stack frames start rolling backwards - which means head will be moving backwards -- am i confusing you with my words?

Comment: And does it *have* to be a singly-linked list? Doubly-linked lists are generally easier to work with, and would be *much* easier in this case. You're not confusing me so much with the words as with what I view as convoluted code. If you've only got a singly-linked list to work with though, that may be *somewhat* inevitable... although I don't think it's *entirely* inevitable. Will see what I can do.

Comment: With a doubly linked list - yes we can solve the problem efficiently in 3-5 lines. But more than the solution to this palindrome problem, I am more interested in hacking pass-by-reference in this case. Had i not created the MyClass wrapper and instead just send a ListNode mover - it is never going to move forward. Is there a way to achieve this without a wrapper class in my question

Comment: Well in your specific situation, you're maintaining two separate pieces of state, which means the "normal" hack of using `AtomicReference` wouldn't work. You could use an `AtomicReference` and an `AtomicBoolean` of course - but I'd hope that actually you could avoid maintaining the state of the boolean anyway, but retaining the return value when you make the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

A classic hack for doing something like this in Java is to pass an array argument of one element.  The array itself is passed by reference and the function may manipulate the 1st element.  Something like this:

```
myMethod(int arr[], int anotherArg) {
   arr[0] = 123;
}

// Use like this:
int myArr[] = {321}
myMethod(arr, 0)
// myMethod() has "returned" something in arr's 1st element.
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need the extra class because you've got *two* pieces of information to maintain - and you've only got two pieces of information to maintain because you're ignoring the return value of the recursive call. I suspect that you could change your code to use `AtomicReference` instead:

```
public boolean checkPalindrome(ListNode head,
                               AtomicReference<ListNode> tailRef,
                               int len) {
    if (head == null || len == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    len--;

    boolean ret = checkPalindrome(head.next, tailRef, len);
    ListNode tail = tailRef.get().next;        
    tailRef.set(tail);
    return ret && head.value == tail.value;
}
```

I haven't checked it thoroughly, but if it's not *quite* there, you should be able to fix it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

sample code below:

```
static LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("A");
    boolean result = CheckPalindrome(list.subList(0, list.size()));
    System.out.println("List " + list + "is Palindrome?");
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean CheckPalindrome(List<String> linkedL) {
    if (linkedL.size() <= 1)
        return true;
    if (linkedL.get(0).equals(linkedL.get(linkedL.size() - 1))) {
        return CheckPalindrome(linkedL.subList(1, linkedL.size() - 1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```